# Is AWS SNS adding apns-push-type & apns-priority to its iOS push notification headers?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

According to [Apple's APNs docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns), as of iOS 13 clients of the http api **must** send header fields for `apns-push-type` and `apns-priority` or the requests will fail. Sure enough, our users who've udpated to the iOS 13 beta aren't getting silent push notifications that we send through AWS/SNS.

AFAICT, there's no way to "inject" these header fields into the request that SNS actually sends. But it seems like Amazon should just be doing this as a matter of course since without it, billions of notifications will soon start to fail.

Anyone know if they have plans to do this soon? Or maybe they're doing it already and I'm missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Good news! AWS announced that SNS now supports additional mobile push notification headers as message attributes.

This change is good for iOS 13, and includes the apns-push-type, apns-priority, and apns-topic headers.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-sns-now-supports-additional-mobile-push-notification-headers-as-message-attributes/

Answer (score 3):

Amazon responded to our support ticket:

> Thank you for contacting AWS Support. I'm *** and I'll be assisting you today regarding this case.
>
> I understand that Apple is going to enforce a new protocol in iOS 13. As per new protocol, all the HTTP notifications must have 'apns-push-type' and 'apns-priority' fields in their headers.
>
> We are aware of this issue and the engineering team is working towards to resolve the issue. Unfortunately, there is no workarounds and the support team  does not have any visibility into the engineering team's  roadmap and ETA for features so I'm unable to provide a date when support for iOS 13 headers will be available. I strongly recommend you to keep an eye on AWS Release notes for an update regarding this issue[1].
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience and I hope that the engineering team resolves the issue as early as possible.

Comment: That's really weird. Like I said in my answer, notifications from SNS to an iOS 13 device are working fine for me. It's just silent notifications that fail.

Comment: It makes sense I think. Apple is setting `apns-priority` to 10 by default and as they say, “it's an error to specify this priority for a notification whose payload contains the content-available key.” So alert notifications are going to be fine, but silent notifications are going to have an invalid `apns-priority`.

Comment: I've updated my answer below: I think that APNs and/or iOS 13 is not yet enforcing the `apns-push-type` header requirement. Will be interesting to see how this develops as the iOS 13 release date approaches...

Comment: Good news: Amazon pushed a fix for this last night. Silent notifications are working reliably with SNS and iOS 13. Whew!

Comment: can you share the sample payload with background push or your ticket url

Comment: The raw SNS payload would look something like this:

{
 "MessageStructure":"json",
 "Message":"{
  \"default\":\"message\",
  \"APNS\":\"{
   \\\"aps\\\":{
    \\\"content-available\\\":1
   },
   \\\"foo\\\":\\\"bar\\\"
  }\",
  \"APNS_SANDBOX\":\"{
   \\\"aps\\\":{
    \\\"content-available\\\":1
   },
   \\\"foo\\\":\\\"bar\\\"
  }
 \"}",
 "TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:0123456789:my_update_name"
}

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In my testing it seems like SNS *does* add the `apns-push-type` field.</strike> Actually, it seems like Apple / iOS is not yet enforcing the `apns-push-type` field requirement. Pushes sent via [Knuff](https://github.com/KnuffApp/Knuff) do not contain this header, and yet they are received by an iOS 13 beta 8 device. I can also receive prominent notifications (i.e. user visible notifications) on an iOS 13 device, sent via SNS. Do prominent notifications work for you?

Since you said that you're only noticing problems with silent notifications, perhaps you are running into this conflict with the `apns-priority` value:

> **apns-priority** The priority of the notification. If you omit this header, APNs sets the notification priority to 10.
>
> Specify 10 to send the notification immediately. A value of 10 is
>   appropriate for notifications that trigger an alert, play a sound, or
>   badge the app’s icon. **It's an error to specify this priority for a
>   notification whose payload contains the content-available key.**
>
> **Specify 5 to send the notification based on power considerations on
>   the user’s device. Use this priority for notifications whose payload
>   includes the content-available key.** Notifications with this priority
>   might be grouped and delivered in bursts to the user’s device. They
>   may also be throttled, and in some cases not delivered.

Attempting to send a notification with `apns-priority = 10` and the `content-available` key (used for silent pushes) is an error. Maybe that's why your silent pushes are being dropped?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't know if alert notifications are working for our app because we don't send them, only silent. In your testing you're successfully getting alert notifications, but have you also tried silent (`content-available`) notifications?

Comment: I just gave it a go with the `content-available` flag and it doesn't work for me either via SNS. The same payload sends fine when I use Knuff, provided that I set the priority to `5`. I'm wondering if SNS is sending all notifications with `apns-priority = 10`. This would definitely result in the notification being dropped.

Comment: The apple doc says - "It is an error to use this priority for a push notification that contains only the content-available key." @shocking The word "only" is missing in your answer and that will change the meaning of that rule :-) May be Apple updated their doc later ?