# iOS 13 - silent push notifications are no longer reliable

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios13

iOS 13 changes:

Change 1: In iOS 13 Beta 6, a silent remote notification (AKA Background Notification) with priority 10 is no longer handled by the OS and dropped. This was documented in the past but never enforced.

[Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc):

***It's an error to specify this priority (10) for a notification whose payload contains the content-available key.***

Log:

> error 14:11:19.224387 +0300 dasd Not Supported: High-priority silent push. (App=)
>
> default 14:11:19.224713 +0300 dasd Daemon Canceling Activities: {(   com.apple.pushLaunch.com.some.bundle:64660B )}
>
> default 14:11:19.225032 +0300 dasd CANCELED: com.apple.pushLaunch.com.some.bundle:64660B at priority 10 !
>
> default 14:11:19.225363 +0300 dasd Removing a launch request for application  by activity

Change 2: a new key, apns-push-type, is required when delivering notifications to devices running iOS 13 with the value `background` or `alert`.

After complying with the above, I'm still seeing random behavior regarding silent remote notifications. I can see that the notification arrives to the device and in some cases (even when the device is connected to a power source) the notification is dropped by the OS.

Fail Log:

> default   12:19:33.450155 +0300   dasd    Submitted Activity: com.apple.pushLaunch.some.bundle:3B0049 at priority 5 <§private>
>
> default   12:19:33.457216 +0300   dasd    Push not allowed for <§private>
>
> default   12:19:33.457355 +0300   dasd    Daemon Canceling Activities: {(
>       com.apple.pushLaunch.some.bundle:3B0049
>   )}

Success log:

> default   14:37:33.633462 +0300   dasd    Submitted Activity:
>    com.apple.pushLaunch.com.some.bundle:D1EEDF at priority 5 <§private>
>
> default   14:37:33.639191 +0300   dasd    Adding a launch request (<§private>)
>    for application  by activity <§private>
>
> default   14:37:33.639240 +0300   dasd    Launch requests for <§private>:
>    <§private>

Going back to the doc:

***Specify 5 to send the notification based on power considerations on the user’s device. Use this priority for notifications whose payload includes the content-available key. Notifications with this priority might be grouped and delivered in bursts to the user’s device. They may also be throttled, and in some cases not delivered.***

From what I'm seeing, silent notifications are throttled and not delivered randomly (even if the battery is full and the device is connected to a power source)

Still trying to figure out if this is the correct behavior or a bug that Apple is going to fix.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57578083/is-aws-sns-adding-apns-push-type-apns-priority-to-its-ios-push-notification-he?r=SearchResults

Comment: Thanks, matt. The last comment there says: "Good news: Amazon pushed a fix for this last night. Silent notifications are working reliably with SNS and iOS 13." This is not what I'm seeing.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. This suggests there is a solution though. :)

Comment: It works better on iOS13 GM version.

Comment: In testing, it looks like when an app is built with Xcode 11 GM, silent notifications from SNS are received as expected while the app is running in the foreground or background. But if the app was built with a prior Xcode 11 beta, then silent notifications from SNS are only received while the app is running in the foreground.

Comment: Did you get a solution? Can you add sample payload?

Comment: still, have this problem in iOS 13.2, as soon as open the app (switch to foreground they will be delivered)!
@Segev any update?

Thanks

Comment: @MoFarhand Im having the same behaviour on iOS 13.2.3

Comment: BTW I eventually solved my problem by adding a header attribute:
--message-attributes '{"AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PUSH_TYPE":{"DataType":"String","StringValue":"background"}}'

Comment: any updates @Segev?